# plotting multiple date-time columns on y-axis and their corresponding ids on x-axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have got a csv/excel file with document id and their corresponding date-time columns. tried the below approach:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas as pd
xls_data = pd.read_excel(<file-path>)

x1 = xls_data["client_doc_id"].values #id column in the file
y1 = xls_data["planned_finish_ifd"].values #one of the date-time column in the file

plt.plot(x1,y1)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

But I am unable to get the desired output instead it is showing the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

how can I plot one date-time column and how can I plot multiple date-time columns in one graph?

Comment: Try with `x1 = pd.to_datetime(xls_data["client_doc_id"])` instead of using the `values` attribute

Comment: i assume you are trying to say `y1 = pd.to_datetime(xls_data["planned_finish_ifd"])` instead of `x1 = pd.to_datetime(xls_data["client_doc_id"])`.                                                   
Hence i used in this way but i got another error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '200-20-PE-DEC-0001'`

Comment: if not i didnt get why the document-id field has to be changed to datetime? since `x1 = pd.to_datetime(xls_data["client_doc_id"])` is related to the document id column.

Comment: I’m sorry, I meant try `y1 = pd.to_datetime(xls_data["planned_finish_ifd"])` instead of `y1 = xls_data["planned_finish_ifd"]` but somewhere between formulating and typing my comment that got switched to the x values.

Comment: Did tried but got another error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '200-20-PE-DEC-0001'`. where `'200-20-PE-DEC-0001'` is a document id.

Comment: Is `'200-20-PE-DEC-0001'` in column `'planned_finish_ifd' `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206581/discussion-between-deepak-harish-and-william-miller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x1 = xls_data["client_doc_id"]
y1 = xls_data["planned_finish_ifd"]
```

instead of `.values` use it normally as a series.

I didn't get at first because of my `matplotlib` version, which is `2.0.2`. I then updated it to latest version. Now it worked. attaching the image of the plot. (Ignore the x-axis-which contains the doc ids).
[image: plot of doc_ids vs date of issue]